# How to count rows of a particular column using formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that contains case number column and MC column. How to count the row of case number based on the MC Column and automatically sum up in the number of cases column. This is the screenshot of my data:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:C; "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C")
```

Comment: How do i sort it by (1-3 days), (4-14 days), (31-90 days), (>90 days), (Fatal), (No MC)?

Comment: @Sriram keep the D column as in your image and use this in E2: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, QUERY(A2:C; "select C,count(C) where C is not null group by C"), 2, 0)))`